# First Stored Procedure - Can't get variable to work

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

This is my first shot at writing a stored procedure. I'm trying to get a list of all orders placed between two dates. I would run this proc monthly, getting the orders for the trailing 6 months. If I ran it on the 2nd or the 15th of the month, it would still take the previous 6 months from the end of the previous month.

Here's the code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pMonthlyCustomerReport 
    -- Get the last day of the previous month and the first day of 6 months ago
    @enddate date,
    @startdate date
AS
    SET @enddate = DATEADD(D,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0));
    SET @startdate = DATEADD(M, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-6, 0);

    -- Get orders for the past 6 months
    SELECT acct_num, date as OrderDate, type as OrderType
    INTO #Orders
    FROM rders
    WHERE date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate;
```

When I run the proc, I get this error message:

> Procedure or function 'pMonthlyCustomerReport' expects parameter '@enddate', which was not supplied.

Any suggestions or best practices I should be using here? I may be over-thinking creating the `@enddate`, `@startdate` and should just put them in the query, but I want the variable to be declared up front.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just declare the vars @startdate and @enddate instead of making them parameters to the sp, since you are setting them based on the current date anyway:

```
DECLARE @startdate datetime
DECLARE @enddate datetime
```

then declare it like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pMonthlyCustomerReport 
AS
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems here. The first one is that you are declaring input parameters that you are not supplying values for(which is obviously not your intention). Solution: Put them after the `AS` and use `DECLARE` to declare them as local variables.

The second problem is that you are trying to set a value of the declared input parameters. This problem will be solved with the first change.

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
declare @enddate date
declare @startdate date
```

after the

```
AS
```

so they are not declared as parameters that have to be supplied when calling the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for parameters, change @enddate and @startdate to local variables by using declare statements.